# Json4s: Classes defined in method bodies are not supported

Tags: scala, json4s

I have a `Seq` of these:

```
case class IntPane(
                    override val duration: FiniteDuration,
                    override val values: mutable.Map[String, Int],
                    override val default: Int)
  extends BasePane[Int](duration, values, default)
```

I can serialize them by calling `writes()`, using this formatter:

```
implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats +
    FieldSerializer[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]]() +
```

However, I wish to ignore some fields, so I add these lines:

```
implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats +
FieldSerializer[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]]() +
FieldSerializer[IntPane](ignore("duration")) +
FieldSerializer[IntPane](ignore("default"))
```

Now, serialization fails with this cryptic exception:

org.json4s.package$MappingException: Classes defined in method bodies are not supported.
      at org.json4s.reflect.package$.fail(package.scala:93)
      at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder$$anonfun$createConstructorDescriptors$3$$anonfun$15.apply(Reflector.scala:139)
      at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder$$anonfun$createConstructorDescriptors$3$$anonfun$15.apply(Reflector.scala:135)
      at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
      at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
      at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
      at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
      at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
      at org.json4s.reflect.Reflector$ClassDescriptorBuilder$$anonfun$createConstructorDescriptors$3.apply(Reflector.scala:135)

Comment: BEWARE: Both [Json4s](https://github.com/json4s/json4s/issues?utf8=%E29C%93&q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+denial) and [default implementations of Scala maps](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/11203) are vulnerable under DoS/DoW attacks!

Answer (score 0):

I've given it a quick try and the following seems to work:

```
val intPaneFieldSerializer = FieldSerializer[IntPane](ignore("duration") orElse ignore("default"))

implicit val formats: Formats = DefaultFormats + FieldSerializer[scala.collection.mutable.Map[String, Int]]() + intPaneFieldSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

> Classes defined in method bodies are not supported.

The error message indicates that the case class `IntPane` is defined inside a method.

```
  def myMethod() {
    case class IntPane(...)
  }
```

If the the IntPane case class definition is moved outside of the method, it could fix the issue.

```
  case class IntPane(...)

  def myMethod() {
    ...
  }
```